# the scoring average of every name in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = {'Name' : ["ana","ini","unu"],'ID' : ["1027","1028","1029"],'Score1' : [3,5,2], 'Score2' : [5,5,4],'Score3' : [1,2,5]}
```

how can i know the scoring average?

`data["Average"] = data.mean(axis=1)`
i tried to use it but didn't work

Comment: You need to change it to dataframe first? `pd.DataFrame(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries to take the average over the entire row, including `Name` and `ID`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Average"] = df[['Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3']].mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Name    ID  Score1  Score2  Score3   Average
0  ana  1027       3       5       1  3.000000
1  ini  1028       5       5       2  4.000000
2  unu  1029       2       4       5  3.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the "Score" keys first and then pass it to `np.mean` -

```py
np.mean([v for k, v in data.items() if k.startswith('Score')], axis=0)
```

**Output**

```
array([3.        , 4.        , 3.66666667])
```

Comment: add it to data: 

data['average'] = np.mean([v for k, v in data.items() if k.startswith('S')], axis=0)

Comment: In this case, this is not a dataframe anymore, but a dictionary operation. The OP needs more details on whether he wants to remain dictionary or dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `filter` to get descired columns

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Average"] = df.filter(like='Score').mean(axis=1)
```